# I don't know how to include the required positional arguments

Tags: class, python-3.x, arguments

I am unsure how to first of all correct this problem of missing required positional arguments, but after this I am trying to set changeable default values for n, s, x and y. I apologize if this question seems stupid, but I am new and appreciate any and all help.

```
import math

class RegularPolygon:

    def __init__(self, n, s, x, y):
        self.n = 3
        self.side = 1
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def getN(self, n):
        self.n = n
        return self.n

    def getSide(self, s):
        self.side = s
        return self.side

    def getX(self, x):
        self.x = x
        return self.x

    def getY(self, y):
        self.y = y
        return self.y

    def getPerimeter(self, n , s):
        self.perimeter = n * s
        return self.perimeter

    def getArea(self, n, s):
        self.area = (n * math.pow(s, 2)) / ( 4 * math.tan(math.pi / n))
        return self.area
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Pythonstuff\Ch.7\chapter07_unittests.py", line 7, in setUp
self.poly1 = RegularPolygon()
TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'n', 's', 'x', and 'y'
```

Comment: Why do all your `get` methods _set_ your object's attributes?

Comment: I have no idea, I was wondering the same thing. The names are what I need to use from the instructors provided tester so they match.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass values when creating a `RegularPolygon` object:

```
c = RegularPolygon(100, 100, 100, 100)
```

You are now probably writing:

```
c = RegularPolygon()
```

In this class there are four positional arguments and you're not passing any now. As none of these parameters have a default value they're all required so you need to specify exactly four values in this case.

Comment: I am not directly running this, I am using a tester that gives it values. The tester would call something like this RegularPolygon(100, 100, 100, 100) but it tells me the above error.

Comment: @Ethan: in that case, could you include the traceback of the exception? The caller should have provided the arguments but apparently it hasn't.

Comment: I have included it now, and it seems everything is tied to line 7 in my code.

Comment: @Ethan well, but your code does what my answer describes: it's not passing any arguments. It's running: `self.poly1 = RegularPolygon()` so you're missing the arguments there.